# How to create 2 new dataframes by comparing columns based on a condition for 2 other dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

So I have table A as such:

```
    State   Date
0   NY      8/4/18
1   NY      4/3/18
2   GA      2/1/18
3   GA      10/11/18
```

And table B as such:

```
    State   Date
0   NY      5/2/18
1   GA      3/4/18
```

I want to compare the Date value in table B with table A; if the date in table A is <= the date in table B for the corresponding State, then place you that row in Dataframe 1. Otherwise, it goes in Dataframe 2. Resulting sets:

Result set A:

```
    State   Date    
0   NY      4/3/18
1   GA      2/1/18
```

Result set B:

```
    State   Date
2   NY      8/4/18
3   GA      10/11/18
```

Comparing the columns is fairly straightforward, I can use numpy, but I'm not sure the method on how to partition the true's and false's into 2 different datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `merge` the tables `A` and `B` then use `<=` to compare the `Date` like columns in order to create a boolean mask representing the condition where *date in table A is <= the date in table B for the corresponding State*, finally use this mask to filter the rows:

```
d = A.merge(B, on='State', how='left')
m = pd.to_datetime(d['Date_x']) <= pd.to_datetime(d['Date_y'])

df1, df2 = A[m].copy(), A[~m].copy()
```

Result:

```
print(df1)
  State    Date
1    NY  4/3/18
2    GA  2/1/18

print(df2)
  State      Date
0    NY    8/4/18
3    GA  10/11/18
```

Comment: What should m look like? I receive an error "IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)." when trying to run A[m]

Comment: @archingfork Use `how=left` optional parameter while merging the dataframes.